# How to get the ContentType Field From Task List Using REST API In SharePoint 2013

Tags: list, 2013, rest

How can I get the ContentType Field value From Task List Using REST API In SharePoint 2013 ?

I tried this code and i got results for ID, Title etc. but for the ContentType field he returned "deferred"

```
$(document).ready(function() {

jQuery.ajax({
   url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Tasks')/items",
   type: "GET",
   dataType: 'json',
   headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
   success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
  var dataResults = data.d.results;
 alert(JSON.stringify(dataResults));
            },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("error:"+JSON.stringify(xhr));
    }
});

 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task object that is being returned contains "links" to other objects, like the content type. Instead of serializing and returning all objects connected to the requested task, it returns the key field (ContentTypeId), and a "deferred" item that contains the URI to the associated item. So, you could grab that URI and make another request to get whatever info you want about the ContentType. Or try adding `$expand=` to the URI:

`_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Tasks')/items?$expand=ContentType`

The additional parameter tells it to go ahead and serialize the `ContentType` object along with the items.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the REST API [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx), for more information. It sounds as the contet type that is is giving you is the request content type and not the actual item content type. Try adding a ?$select field1,field2,ContentType,field3 to the URL.

Comment: Thanks but I already tried it and the result is still "deferred"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the select parameter, then you must include ContentTypeId in the select statement.
Without using select, you can expand Content Type using (as Mike2500 showed):

```
?$expand=ContentType
```

However, if you add a select it will not expand, unless you include ContentTypeId. For example, neither of these will cause Content Type to be expanded:

```
?$select=Id&$expand=ContentType
?$select=Id,ContentType&$expand=ContentType
```

Now if you include ContentTypeId in the select, then the Content Type will be expanded. For example:

```
?$select=Id,ContentTypeId,ContentType&$expand=ContentType
?$select=Id,ContentTypeId,ContentType/Name&$expand=ContentType
```